# Excluding all hidden files and directories as well as an additional file using rsync

Tags: rsync

I am attempting to use rsync to copy files, but I want to not copy hidden files and folders, and there is one ordinary file I want excluded from the file transfer.  I believe I am eliminating the hidden folders with the --exclude=".*/" and I believe I am excluding the hidden file with the --exclude file path option.  If I eliminate the --exclude file path option, I don't get any errors, but that file is copied, which I do not want.  If I eliminate the --excluude=".*/" the hidden files are copied, which I do not want either.  What am I doing wrong?

```
mbp:~ username $ rsync —-exclude /Users/username/work/java/textsearch/settings/search_config.properties --exclude=".*/" -avz /Users/username/work/java/ root@remote.local:/usr/local/java/ -n
building file list ... rsync: link_stat "/Users/username/?\#200\#224-exclude" failed: No such file or directory (2)
done

sent 9560 bytes  received 20 bytes  6386.67 bytes/sec
total size is 17461760  speedup is 1822.73
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/main.c(992) [sender=2.6.9]
```

1) What is /Users/username/?#200#224-exclude and why is rsync looking for it?

2) How do I get rsync to copy everything except the hidden folders/files and the specified file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is an exact copy of the command line, the "--" in front of exclude is not using the correct characters. Delete this and replace with double minus. What happens is, that rsync doesn't recognize the option, instead searching the user directory for the file "—-exclude"